menu icon id not showing android studio java
I am making an app based on CRUD and I am adding a top menu, I already created the xml in charge of displaying the icons but when I call the id it does not reflect it, there is the code and screenshots
enter image description here enter image description here enter image description here

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Go to gradle.properties and add this line [not recommended] :
android.nonFinalResIds=false 

Use if else to solve this problem [recommended]
Read this article: Breaking changes: build option default values

how to use the if else in my code? @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()){
switch R.id.icon_add:{
Toast.makeText(this, "Agregra", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
}
case R.id.icon_save:{
Toast.makeText(this, "Guardar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
}
case R.id.icon_delate:{
Toast.makeText(this, "Eliminar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;

Thank you very much friend, you have helped me, I have already managed to solve the problem, the if else and the line of code helped me. I LOVE YOU LOL HAHAHA
